# Show that tangent plane of touching point is the same

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-spaces

Let $S_1$, $S_2$ be two regular surfaces such that they touch each other at $p\in S_1\cap S_2$. How can we show that the tangent planes $T_pS_1$ and $T_pS_2$ are identical? Thank you for your help.

Edit:
At the beginning we have $S_1 \cap S_2 = \emptyset$. We then apply a rigid motion (translation) in $S_1$ towards $S_2$, i.e. we move $S_1$ towards $S_2$ and stop immediately when $S_1\cap S_2\neq \emptyset.$ In this case there is $p\in S_1\cap S_2$ and the tangent planes should be identical.

Comment: what do you mean by "touch each other"? If you just mean the surfaces have non-empty intersection, then this alone is not enough to guarantee they have the same tangent planes.

Comment: In fact since a generic intersection is transverse most of the time they won't have the same tangent plane.

Comment: Sorry for being vage. By touching each other I mean at the beginning we have $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$. Then we apply a translation on $S_1$ towards $S_2$ and stop when $S_1\cap S_2\neq \emptyset.$

Comment: @kern711 Is there more information available?  Given the way that you have set this up, it isn't clear the best way that this can be shown.  If you allow rigid motions (translations and rotations), then you can always bring a point on a surface to the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and rotate so that the tangent plane is the $xy$-plane (i.e., $z = 0$).

If you just allow translations, then based on what you have given us there is no expectation that $T_{p}S_{1}$ and $T_{p}S_{2}$ should be identical.  But if you know something about the surfaces, then there are things to try. (Cont.)

Comment: @kern711 For example, if $S_{1}$ is a level set of the form $F_{1}(x, y, z) = c_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ is a level set of the form $F_{2}(x, y, z) = c_{2}$, then you could show that the gradients $\nabla F_{1} (p)$ and $\nabla F_{2} (p)$ are parallel.  Or you can find another way to show that the surfaces have a common normal vector at $p$.  Or you can find a basis for each of $T_{p}S_{1}$ and $T_{p}S_{2}$ and show that they (the bases) span the same subspace of $T_{p}\mathbb{R}^{3}$.  Etc.  What do you have to work with?

Comment: I don't know if it helps but I'll try to make it more specific: let's say $S_1$ is a sphere and $S_2$ is an egg inside $S_1$. Since $S_1$ is closed, if we fix $S_1$ and move $S_2$ around eventually $S_2$ will "hit" $S_1$ from the "inside" at $p$. I want to show that $T_pS_1=T_pS_2$. One of the problems is that I don't know what $S_1$ and $S_2$ exactly are and I also don't know where $p$ is. I only know that such $p$ exists. The surfaces are given locally as graphs of some function. Thank you very much.

Comment: @kern711 If you can assume that $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are both compact surfaces (which is what you are suggesting when $S_{1}$ is a sphere and $S_{2}$ is an egg inside), then here is one idea. You can consider the function $d : S_{1} \times S_{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $d(q, r) = dist(q, r)$.  Since $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$ are compact, then so is $S_{1} \times S_{2}$. As such, the function $d$ must obtain a minimum value, say at points $p_{1} \in S_{1}$ and $p_{2} \in S_{2}$. It is fairly straightforward to show that the line segment from $p_{1}$ to $p_{2}$ must be . . . (Cont.)

Comment: @kern711 . . . perpendicular to both $T_{p_{1}}S_{1}$ and $T_{p_{2}}S_{2}$.  As such, then tangent planes $T_{p_{1}}S_{1}$ and $T_{p_{2}}S_{2}$ must be parallel.  If you slide the surface $S_{2}$ in the direction of the line segment between $p_{2}$ and $p_{1}$ for a distance of $d(p_{1}, p_{2})$, then you should be able to obtain the desired result.

Comment: @THW Thank you very much! It does seem to solve my problem.